# Python: aplanar niveles de lista

Tags: python, array, lista, numpy

Como puedo conseguir aplanar una lista de forma que todas tengan el mismo nivel.

```py
L = [
    [[[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]], [2, 2, 2]], 
    [[[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]], [2, 2, 2]]
    ]
L_result = ... #Código que modifique L.
print (L_result)
[[[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [2, 2, 2]], [[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [2, 2, 2]]]
```

Gracias

Comment: Eso no es exactamente un aplanado, pues lo que obtienes al final aún tiene varios niveles. ¿Cuál sería la especificación concreta del problema? ¿Dejar el resultado con solo tres niveles? ¿Y si en la lista de entrada alguno de los elementos tiene menos de tres niveles? ¿Cómo lo convertirías?

Comment: El ejemplo particular que planteas se resolvería por ejemplo con `L_result = [row[0] + [row[1]] for row in L]`, pero para un caso más general es necesario que especifiques mejor qué formatos posibles podría tener la entrada, y cómo habría de ser la salida en cada caso.

Comment: Quería resolver ese ejemplo concreto, y con tu solución se resuelve perfectamente. Muchas gracias